# Microsoft ODBC SQL Server Driver TCP/IP Sockets SSL Security error

Tags: sql-server

We have just built a new SQL 2019 environment. The application server (Windows 2022) connects to the database server (Windows 2022) successfully. However, for some reason the customer needs to have connectivity between the legacy app server (Windows 2012) and the new database server (Windows 2022). That connectivity however fails with the error message:

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets] SSL Security error

My research so far seems to suggest a TLS mismatch between the two servers.

Does anyone have any experience of how to resolve this issue please?

Thank you

Comment: As I know W2K12 doesn't support TLS 1.2 per default, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server

Comment: You should make that an answer, Mainecoon21.

Comment: @Mainecoon21 thank you for your time and the response. So my understanding of your suggested answer and the link included is that the issue I am experiencing is indeed a TLS mismatch and the W2K12 server not configured for TLS 1.2 is the likely cause of the problem. Is this correct please?

Comment: @PTL_SQL, yes, it's my assumption.

Comment: @Mainecoon21 thank you so much, I appreciate your time and help.